# Angular 2 tutorial : Cannot find module '../../both/collections/parties.collection'

Tags: meteor, angular

I'm following the socially app tutorial : https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3-way-data-binding 
but i'm having an error at step 3 : `Cannot find module ../../both/collections/parties.collection`. Note that typings and typings-core are both installed and i can see them under the node_modules.
So what is causing the error ?

here's my structure :

*parties.collection.ts* is under ***myApp/both/collections/***

My main component file calling the *parties.collection.ts* is under ***myApp/client/imports/app***:

```
import { Parties } from '../../both/collections/parties.collection';
```

Comment: may want to elaborate a bit on the file structure

Comment: I updated my original post

Comment: Try adding another `../` to the path, I think it's looking in the `client` folder with the way it's currently set.

Comment: Following this tutorial, the import is happening in the `app.component.ts` inside the `app` directory, moving the `main.ts` file won't affect that, the path in the import still needs to be updated (they actually have it wrong on the tutorial site too)

Comment: Dave it right, it defiantly needs another `../` in the relative path

Comment: You are right guys. Gosh how they can make such mistakes in an official Tutorial !!

Comment: I agree, a tutorial shouldn't have mistakes, it is hard enough learning the topic! Good job man!

Comment: Lessons learned. Never rely on a tutorial and find the mistake by myself !! Now i need to update the paths everywhere !  Thank you guys and espacially Sasquatch3o3

Comment: For sure, glad to help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `../` to the path, the tutorial has it demonstrated incorrectly.